# How I Can Conver Variable value in Element id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

If I declare value in `A` this value I want to access as id in `B` through `getElementById()`. Can I use this method?

```
var A = 10;
var B = doument.getElementbyId(A)
console.log(B)
```

Comment: You can, but `A` var is an `integer`, you need a string

Comment: `var B = doument.getElementbyId(A.toString())`

Comment: Alternatively `var A = "10";`, provided you have an HTML element with `id="10"` as an attribute. Don't confuse HTML element ids with database IDs. HTML elements can have names as well, doesn't have to be a number.

Comment: Please make it clear whether or not you have created an HTML element with ```id=10```. Until specified, this question can only be seen as JS only question and will be solved using ```Objects``` only.

Answer (score 1):

Case-sensitivity matters in JavaScript.

1. You have a spelling error in "doument" (missing a "c")
2. You have a grammatical error in "getElementbyId" (The "b" should be capitalized)
3. The `id` param of [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) should be a case-sensitive string

You can convert the integer to a string by calling `toString()` on it.

```js
var A = 10;
var B = document.getElementById(A.toString())
console.log(B)
```

```html
<div id="10">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: The only issue I can see is the typo, the type passed to `document.getElementById()` isn't checked: https://jsfiddle.net/uq3t9jkc/

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you are supposed to do that. `document.getElementById` returns the HTML element with that particular id.

This is done using `Objects`.

Try this:

```
var A = 10;

var B = {
    id: A
}

console.log(B.id);
```

Comment: The object is not necessary, `document.getElementById()` simply takes a string that corresponds to an `id` value in the DOM.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes you are right but in the question, it is not mentioned that the user is creating an element with ```id=10```. Until specified by the user, we can only assume that this is a JS only question.

Comment: That makes no sense. There is no requirement for an object to be passed. The only problem in reality is the misspelled `doument`.